# Unable to create dart snapshot for flutter tool

Tags: flutter, dart, initializing, flutter-upgrade

[image]

```
  flutter upgrade
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
Resolving dependencies... (8.1s)
Got dependencies.
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/http-0.13.6/lib/src/base_request.dart:144:7: Error: The getter 'drethrow' isn't defined for the class 'BaseRequest'.
 - 'BaseRequest' is from 'package:http/src/base_request.dart' ('AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/http-0.13.6/lib/src/base_request.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'drethrow'.
      drethrow;
      ^^^^^^^^
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/http-0.13.6/lib/src/base_request.dart:129:28: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'StreamedResponse' doesn't allow null.
 - 'StreamedResponse' is from 'package:http/src/streamed_response.dart' ('AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/http-0.13.6/lib/src/streamed_response.dart').
  Future<StreamedResponse> send() async {
                           ^
Error: Unable to create dart snapshot for flutter tool.
```

I wanted to update Flutter when I ran into this problem. And I can't run my project at all, as if Flutter was not installed at all

I want to be able to update and output

Answer (score 0):

You were most probably looking at the source code of the `http` package the `dart` pub tool downloaded to your computer and accidentally pressed a <kbd>d</kbd> on your keyboard in `AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/http-0.13.6/lib/src/base_request.dart` on line 144 and this made the code incompilable. Go to this file and remove the `d` or run `dart pub cache repair` to redownload all the packages in your pub cache.

```
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'drethrow'.
      drethrow;
      ^^^^^^^^
```

The cause was clearly stated in the error you were getting.